# How to prove the decomposition of k-forms over a complexified vector space?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra

I am studying the book "Complex Geometry, an introduction", page 27. We consider the complexification of a vector space V, namely $V_\mathbb{C}$. If we take the decomposition $$V = W_1 + W_2.$$ Then the following decomposition of the space of k-forms over $V_\mathbb{C}$ follows:
\begin{equation}
\bigwedge^{k} V_\mathbb{C} = \bigoplus_{p+q = k} \bigwedge^p W_1 \otimes_\mathbb{C} \bigwedge^q W_2 
\end{equation}
But I do not know how to prove it. Even understanding the equalities as isomorphisms, if $\alpha \otimes \beta \in  \bigwedge^p W_1 \otimes_\mathbb{C} \bigwedge^q W_2 $. How do I define an element of $\bigwedge^{k} V_\mathbb{C}$ from $\alpha \otimes \beta$ ? My biggest problem is that $\alpha$ only p vectors from $W_1$ and $\beta$ only q vectors from $W_2$, but I need to construct an (antisymmetric) object that takes p+q vectors from $V_\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Take the $W_1$-component of the first $p$ vectors and insert them into $\alpha$, take the $W_2$-component of the last $q$ vectors and insert them into $\beta$, then multiply the two. This will you give you a linear map from the RHS to the LHS. To check that this is an isomorphism, it is probably best to write down bases of both sides in terms of chosen bases of $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Comment: Sorry, that previous comment contains an error. You have to take the *antisymmetrization* of the multilinear map I described. In other words, if $p_I\colon V_{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow W_i,\,i=1,2$ are the projections associated to this decomposition, you take $\alpha\otimes\beta\mapsto p_1^{\ast}\alpha\wedge p_2^{\ast}\beta$.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try it with this approach!

Comment: Maybe it is suitable to first show that (in the light of @Thorgott first comment) that $V_{\Bbb C}^{\otimes k} = \bigoplus_{p+q = k} W_1^{\otimes p}\otimes_{\Bbb C} W_2^{\otimes q}$, and then to anti-symmetrize things